# Powershell Invoke-SQLcmd Query argument inconsistent?

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I do apologies if this has been asked before. At the time I wrote this I was unable to find this behavior addressed on this site.

When using Invoke-SQLcmd in powershell I get inconsistencies. I receive SQL connection arguments at the scripts invocation from the user. Inside of the this single test script I have two queries. Both invocations use the same variables.

***This works*** and returns the name of the database.

```
$ConnectQuery = "SELECT DBName = DB_NAME()"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $SQLDBName -Username $SQLUsername -Password $SQLPassword -Query $ConnectQuery
```

***This does not work*** but does not give me an error but returns nothing. I checked the variables and they continue to have the same content as that this query immediately follows the previous.

```
$ConnectQuery01 = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[test.csv]"
    
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $SQLDBName -Username $SQLUsername -Password $SQLPassword -Query $ConnectQuery01
```

**Additional Notes:**

As I understand Invoke-Sqlcmd it is a module that provides Powershell access to the same features as the command shell command "sqlcmd". So I tried this using "sqlcmd". In both cases, these commands worked and return the expected data The databases name, and the table content which is a single test row.

In SQLcmd executable:

**These both work** and return the expected data.

```
sqlcmd -S <MyDesktopName> -d test -U "<TestAccountName>" -P "<TestPassword>" -q "SELECT DBName = DB_NAME()"
```

```
sqlcmd -S <MyDesktopName> -d test -U "<TestAccountName>" -P "<TestPassword>" -q "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[test.csv]"
```

In SSMS:

**These both work** and return the expected data.

```
SELECT DBName = DB_NAME()
```

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[test.csv]
```

**Just in case someone asks**

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                         
----                           -----                                                                                                                         
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.1171                                                                                                                
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                       
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                       
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.1171                                                                                                               
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                               
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                           
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3    
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: Are you sure there's data in `[dbo].[test.csv]` If you use SSMS to query the table as the same user, do you get rows?

Comment: Yes I use SSMS and SQLcmd.exe and both return the single row of data that I inserted in that table.

Comment: Ok I think I have found a way to mitigate this behavior. If I do this:$MyResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $SQLDBName -Username $SQLUsername -Password $SQLPassword -Query $ConnectQuery01

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I have found a way to mitigate this behavior.

If I do this:

`$ConnectQuery01 = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[test.csv]"`

`$MyResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $SQLDBName -Username $SQLUsername -Password $SQLPassword -Query $ConnectQuery01`

Then I do this:

`Write-Host $MyResult. | Format-Table`

I get the table results that I expect. This is significantly different behavior from the first evocation of "Invoke-sqlcmd" So, I believe that there are different return behaviors depending on the expected return. I could be wrong here. Please let me know if you have a better explanation.

Thank you for you attention.